# What does "The devil take the waltz, my only regret is for the coda—I wish that had been a success!" mean?

Tags: meaning

> "The devil take the waltz, my only regret is for the coda—I wish that had been a success!", Johann Strauss II said

I don't understand what [he said](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blue_Danube), and what he means to.

Comment: Which part of this construction do you not understand? I think it's all General Reference, but I'll wait awhile before voting to close, in case clarification improves the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The Devil take ***_*__*_*_**" is a somewhat archaic way of saying "I don't care about ***_*__*_***" - after all, the Devil can have it.

As for a [Coda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coda_%28music%29), it is the final portion of a piece of music -  and in the case of the *Blue Danube*, the segment of which Strauss was proudest.

Comment: And even though he was proudest of that part, it seems even that was not well received generally. (He didn't care that the rest of it wasn't well received)

Comment: As from my understanding, so he not care what the waltz music like but he want to put his sadness to the end of song. Is my understanding true ?

Comment: @AtomSkaaskaHic Not exactly -  after all, he wrote the song. More accurately, he didn't care what *people thought of the waltz* -  it was unimportant to him, so long as they liked the Coda. (Sadly, they did not.)

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the idiom "The devil take the hindmost" I would say that the writer wasn't really that fond of the piece in general, but just the portion of it called the "coda".

Comment: "[Devil take the hindmost](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/358400.html)" has nothing to do with fondness for something; it instead says that those who lag behind will receive no aid, ie stragglers are out of luck. Also, per [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/devil_take_the_hindmost), look to yourself first.